What does the equation of the law of conservation of total mechanical energy with deformation energy look like?
I considered task with elastic collision of two balls ($m$ and $M$) on horizontal surface.
It needs law of conservation of total mechanical energy and law of conservation of momentum to solve this task.
I have question about law of conservation of total mechanical energy for this task.
Equation of the law of conservation of total mechanical energy for this task:
$$E_1 + E_2 = E_1' + E_2'$$
$$\frac{mv_1^2}{2} + \frac{Mv_2^2}{2}  = \frac{mv_1'^2}{2} + \frac{Mv_2'^2}{2}$$
I read that there is deformation energy which can be neglected in equation of the law of conservation of total mechanical energy. But I didn't find anything about deformation energy for this example.
What does the equation of the law of conservation of total mechanical energy with deformation energy look like?
Thanks.

Isn't it as simple as adding of U1 + U2 to the left part and U'1 + U'2 to the right part where U is internal energy calculated from temperature of the body...?

I think the question is about how to account for strain energy.  In a perfectly elastic collision, there will be no change in internal energy.

The reason you "neglect" deformation energy is that it isn't necessary for the calculation, especially in the case of perfectly elastic contact.  The only time you might want to include it is if you are interested in the amount of deformation in the balls, or some other detail about the moment of contact.
You can google "Hertz Strain Energy" if you want the full math description.  But I would suggest first assuming contact is governed by a simple compression-only spring law.  You will see that the spring is at rest state just before the collision, compresses to a maximum when the ball velocities are at a minimum, and then goes back to rest state as the balls separate. So the "before collision" and "after collision" energy in the spring is zero.  As it would be even with a more sophisticated accounting of strain energy (neglecting residual compression waves).
Also, incidentally, if you consider both masses as a combined system, the collision forces between them will be an equal and opposite pair. So in a FBD of both masses, the collision force is internal and does not change the overall system momentum.  That's why you can use momentum conservation.
Of course, this is all an idealization that neglects friction, energy loss, etc.  But maybe it helps conceptually.
